# Using optional groups in positive lookbehind

Tags: regex

Boy, I suck at Regex.

I need to match newlines and whitespaces between `IMG` BBCodes in series so I can replace them with single whitespace. But the problem is they also could be wrapped with `URL` tags (so this means the `URL` tag is optional). Here are some possible combinations:

```
[/img]    [img ...]

[/img][/url]
     [url ...][img ...]

[/img]     [url ...][img ...]

[/img][/url]    
    [img ...]
```

I've came along this far:

```
(?:\[\/img\](?:\[\/url\])?)([\s]+)(?=(?:\[url(?:.+?)?\])?\[img(?:.+?)?\])
```

Sadly, it also matches BBCodes which I don't want to. Please [check it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wG3aM3/865) (I want green ones - `Group 1` only).

I can't use positive lookbehind because it says "A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed" when I try to make `URL` tag optional. [See my attempt here](https://regex101.com/r/wG3aM3/867).

What should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?x)                        # Verbose mode
(                           # Capture Group 1
    \[/img\]                # Matches [/img]
    (?:\[/url[^\]]*\])?     # Optionally match [/url ... ]
)
(\s{2,})                    # Capture Group 2: Matches 2 or more white space characters
(                           # Capture Group 3
    (?:\[url[^\]]*\])?      # Optionaly matches [url ... ]
    \[img[^\]]*\]           # Matches [img ... ]
)
```

Replace with `\1 \3`.

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c1GYXe/2/)